# the switch-statement gives the wrong month how to fix?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, monthcalendar

I am trying to get the current month and then put the month inside a div.

```
function checkmaand()
{
var datum = new Date();
var maand = datum.getMonth();
switch (maand)
{   
    case 0: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Januari";
    case 1: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Februari";
    case 2: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Maart";
    case 3: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "April";
    case 4: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Mei";
    case 5: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Juni";
    case 6: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Juli";
    case 7: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Augustus";
    case 8: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "September";
    case 9: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Oktober";
    case 10: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "November";
    case 11: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "December";
}
}
```

But for some reason the output is December (it is nov right now for the people in the future)

So my question is why does it do that and how can i fix it?

one more thing: I have to make it with javascript.

Comment: Tip: set document.getElementById("maand") as a variable instead of repeating it. var target = document.getElementById("maand"), then use target.innerHTML(...);

Comment: @Diodeus Or even simpler: store the monts in a variable and append it after the swich statement. @OP: your missing the `break;` statements (and a default), so you'll always end up with the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (expr) {
  case "Oranges":
    document.write("Oranges are $0.59 a pound.<br>");
    break;
  case "Apples":
    document.write("Apples are $0.32 a pound.<br>");
    break;
```

In the example of **HC_** .

The break is optional but as the explanation will show :

The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. **If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement**.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a `break;` at the end of every case so that it doesn't continue to the next one.

```
function checkmaand()
{
var datum = new Date();
var maand = datum.getMonth();
switch (maand)
{   
    case 0: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Januari";
        break;
    case 1: document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = "Februari";
        break;
   ...
}
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the "break" at the end of each case.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the problem is because you forgot to add a `break;` at the end of each of your case statements.

As a suggestion, you can simplify your code like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/waqqas_abdulkareem/Le94k/):

```
function checkmaand() {
    document.getElementById("maand").innerHTML = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][new Date().getMonth()];
}
```